# Java - Importing images and resizing them

Tags: java, image, jbutton, scale, imageicon

Ive been looking for a simpler way to bring images into my program, and resizing them. Im not looking for a complicated way, using buffered images and such, unless i need to. Currently im doing it this way.

```
    ImageIcon i = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("img.png"));
    Image bigImage = i.getImage();
    Image smallImage = bigImage.getScaledInstance(100, 100, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
    ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(smallImage);
```

I want the final image to be an Image Icon and 100,100. Currently this method seems to cut off a little of the image, but that could just be because im using it as an icon for a jbutton. If its the JButton thats cutting off a few pixels, is their any way around this? Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you try accepting answers from other questions before posting new questions.? You have posted 19 question and have yet to accept a single answer. I think I skip this question.

Comment: When others already answer it, as they do, i dont find it necessary to rewrite what they say.

Comment: Nobody said anything about rewriting what they say. An answer should be "accepted", when it answers your question.